# Why did my wasteland explorers trade out their weapons?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I sent 2 dwellers to the wasteland and waited a few hours.

I found that both had traded out their weapons from shotguns to a mini-gun and a plasma pistol.

Why would they do that?

Comment: For the best strategy send out your most SPECIAL dweller (highest stats in everything) and give them your best Armor and Weapon. You'll find this strategy quickly leaves you swimming in Caps and gear.

Comment: Why would you *not* want them to use better weapons?

Answer (score 14):

Assuming you're referring to typical shotguns (there are various types of shotguns with different damage ratings) and typical a typical mini-gun or plasma pistol, they traded their weapons because the new weapon had a higher damage rating (which, as far as I know, is the only stat for weapons). This happens automatically when dwellers locate higher damage weapons in the Wasteland.